# Optimizing width of table (tabulary)

Tags: tables, width, tabulary

I'm trying to fit this table to the width of the page, however, whenever I try to change the header width with the command `{p{}}` it doesn't adjust the width of the three main headers `Population`, `Associations` and `Gymnasts`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{tabulary}
        \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{float,lscape}
        \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}

        \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1907}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{R|RRRR|RR|RRRRR}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Population} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Associations} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Gymnasts} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Nation} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Size (km2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Inhabitants} & Inhabitants per km2 & Inhabitants per association & Associations & km2 per association & Total & 100 km2 & per 100 km2 & Inhabitants per gymnast & per association \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Germany} & 636'478 & 60'000'000 & 94    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7'960} & 7'538 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{84} & 772'134 & 6'365 & 121   & 78    & 102 \bigstrut[t]\\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Hungary} & 282'804 & 45'885'000 & 162   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{899'706} & 51    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5'545} & 9'000 & 2'828 & 3     & 5'098 & 176 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Great Britain} & 314'628 & 40'635'000 & 129   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-} & -     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{France} & 536'488 & 40'500'000 & 75    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39'901} & 1'015 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{529} & 250'000 & 5'365 & 47    & 162   & 246 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Italy} & 286'648 & 31'478'000 & 110   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{296'962} & 106   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2'704} & 13'175 & 2'866 & 5     & 2'389 & 124 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Czech countries} & 79'320 & 8'725'000 & 110   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12'831} & 680   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{117} & 56'000 & 793   & 71    & 156   & 82 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Belgium} & 29'457 & 7'200'000 & 244   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{33'488} & 215   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{137} & 16'953 & 295   & 58    & 425   & 79 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Netherlands} & 33'000 & 6'000'000 & 182   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30'303} & 198   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{167} & 14'671 & 330   & 44    & 409   & 74 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Sweden} & 450'754 & 5'066'000 & 11    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{144'743} & 35    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12'879} & 2'200 & 4'508 & 0.5   & 2'303 & 63 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Switzerland} & 41'419 & 3'314'000 & 80    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4'845} & 684   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{61}} & 51'766 & 414   & 125   & 64    & 76 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Norway} & 322'305 & 2'230'000 & 7     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17'840} & 125   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2'578} & 8'500 & 3'223 & 3     & 262   & 68 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Denmark} & 38'340 & 2'187'000 & 57    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{95'087} & 23    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1'667} & 3'000 & 383   & 8     & 729   & 130 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Luxembourg} & 2'587 & 219'000 & 85    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10'950} & 20    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{129} & 1'375 & 26    & 53    & 159   & 69 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabulary}%
    \vspace{5pt}
    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Source: Spühler (1907), own illustration}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to adjust the table width so that it fits the page (it wouldn't be a tragedy if it exceeds the text width, but it should be fully visible)?

Furthermore, how can I increase the margin of the headers in the second row to the top (at present the headers are to close to the top `\hline`)?

Comment: why have you specified `R` for the first column but then over-ridden that specification with a `\multicolumn` entry in _every_ cell? That is likely to confuse tabulary quite a bit...

Comment: I wrote the table with tabular and then found out that tabulary is better suited for this kind of table and therefore switched over to tabulary in the belief that it would work.

Comment: but with tabular the same comment applies, using \multicolumn in every cell in a column is never useful

Comment: The example produces the error message `! Undefined control sequence.
l.40     \captionsetup
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabulary` isn't really suited to numeric data, better to use `tabular` for this kind of table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{tabulary}
        \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{float,lscape}
        \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}

\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
        \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1907}
  \tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.7pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrrrrr@{}}
    \toprule
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nation}
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Population} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Associations} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Gymnasts}\\
\cmidrule(rl){1-2}
\cmidrule(rl){3-5}
\cmidrule(rl){6-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-12}
    & \hd{Size\\(km\textsuperscript{2})} & 
\hd{Total} &
\hd{per\\km\textsuperscript{2}}&
\hd{per\\assoc.} &
\hd{Total} &
\hd{km\textsuperscript{2} per\\assoc.} & Total & 
\hd{Size\\(100km\textsuperscript{2})} & 
\hd{per\\100km\textsuperscript{2}} & 
\hd{Inhabitants\\ per gymnast} &
\hd{per\\assoc.}\\
\cmidrule(rl){1-2}
\cmidrule(rl){3-5}
\cmidrule(rl){6-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-12}
    {Germany} & 636'478 & 60'000'000 & 94    & {7'960} & 7'538 & {84} & 772'134 & 6'365 & 121   & 78    & 102 \bigstrut[t]\\
    {Hungary} & 282'804 & 45'885'000 & 162   & {899'706} & 51    & {5'545} & 9'000 & 2'828 & 3     & 5'098 & 176 \\
    {Great Britain} & 314'628 & 40'635'000 & 129   & {-} & -     & {} & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    {France} & 536'488 & 40'500'000 & 75    & {39'901} & 1'015 & {529} & 250'000 & 5'365 & 47    & 162   & 246 \\
    {Italy} & 286'648 & 31'478'000 & 110   & {296'962} & 106   & {2'704} & 13'175 & 2'866 & 5     & 2'389 & 124 \\
    {Czech countries} & 79'320 & 8'725'000 & 110   & {12'831} & 680   & {117} & 56'000 & 793   & 71    & 156   & 82 \\
    {Belgium} & 29'457 & 7'200'000 & 244   & {33'488} & 215   & {137} & 16'953 & 295   & 58    & 425   & 79 \\
    {Netherlands} & 33'000 & 6'000'000 & 182   & {30'303} & 198   & {167} & 14'671 & 330   & 44    & 409   & 74 \\
    {Sweden} & 450'754 & 5'066'000 & 11    & {144'743} & 35    & {12'879} & 2'200 & 4'508 & 0.5   & 2'303 & 63 \\
    {Switzerland} & 41'419 & 3'314'000 & 80    & {4'845} & 684   & {\textbf{61}} & 51'766 & 414   & 125   & 64    & 76 \\
    {Norway} & 322'305 & 2'230'000 & 7     & {17'840} & 125   & {2'578} & 8'500 & 3'223 & 3     & 262   & 68 \\
    {Denmark} & 38'340 & 2'187'000 & 57    & {95'087} & 23    & {1'667} & 3'000 & 383   & 8     & 729   & 130 \\
    {Luxembourg} & 2'587 & 219'000 & 85    & {10'950} & 20    & {129} & 1'375 & 26    & 53    & 159   & 69 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \vspace{5pt}
%    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Source: Spühler (1907), own illustration}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```